# How to create a class constructor which accepts parameters in curly braces in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a Matrix class which has a vector of vectors as its member.

```
class Matrix{
public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(/*what goes here?*/) : /*here*/
    {
        /*and here?*/
    }
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> contents;
}
```

According to the instructions in my assignment, it should be possible to implement a constructor which will accept the data in the same way as a vector of vectors:

```
Matrix M({{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}});
```

My question is how should I specify the type of the argument in the constructor and how can I pass it to the `contents` member?

Comment: you can remove all your user defined constructors and construct it via `Matrix M{{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}};`

Comment: Have you tried to use the exact same type as the variable itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Matrix
{
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> contents;
public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(const decltype(contents) & _contents)
        : contents(_contents)
    {}
};
```

Comment: This was by far the most helpful. Turns out all I needed was `const` since the values are passed directly in the source code, but I'm glad that I learned what `decltype` is along the way. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
struct Matrix {
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> contents;
};
```

> Good design is as little design as possible 
> -- Dieter Rams

Comment: though this requires `Matrix M{{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}};` not exaclty what OP was asking for, but I guess thats fine

Comment: @463035818 from what OP's instructor said, that should be fine. It's also possible to take vector by value and then move to get the exact syntax. You can add an answer doing that. I would definitely vote on that.

Comment: nah, theres not much to add to this answer. I am tempted to write an answer along the line of "just use the `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` directly." That would be minimal design :P, but thats silly

Comment: `using Matrix = float[3][3];` :) but then you lose a) type distinction; b) ability to add member functions.

Comment: It has to be a class, also I was hoping to learn how to generally implement classes which accept an undefined number of parameters in curly braces.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Parens become accepted since c++20: https://godbolt.org/z/G75Eb1vEj

Comment: @FranciszekJurasz this *is* a class.

Comment: "Perfection is achieved, not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing left to take away." — Antoine de Saint-Exupéry

Answer (score 2):

Make a constructor that accepts a `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`.
It's also a good idea to move the parameter to avoid extra copying.

```
#include <vector>

class Matrix{
public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(std::vector<std::vector<float>> vec) : contents(std::move(vec)) {}
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> contents;
};

int main() {
  Matrix M({{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}});
}
```